# The neural network cannot correctly output the results

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, reinforcement-learning

I am training an agent based on clipping proximal policy optimization (PPO-clip) algorithm with an actor-critic structure. However, the actor network cannot normally output the probability vectors as well as iteration steps when it is training, despite of the fact that I did nothing different for the two utilizations of actor.
As we know, the agent needs iteration steps for experiences to train the network, which is the intelligent core. In PPO-clip for each step, the agent moves according to the action which is selected by actor:

```
def action_select(self, obs):
    posibilities = self.actor(obs).cpu().detach()
    print(posibilities)
```

`obs` is the current state inputted into actor then to come out the posibilities, which is a vector with the identical dimension as the discrete action space. Commonly, the posibilities vector should be outputted like this:

```
tensor([[0.0135, 0.0221, 0.0847, 0.1862, 0.2241, 0.2183, 0.1882, 0.0619]])
```

In PPO-clip, there is another place to use actor network. During training process for each batchsize, the current probability `cur_probs` of corresponding action should be calculated for the ratio between current probability and previous probability:

```
cur_probs = self.reshape(states[index]).to(device).gather(1, actions[index])
ratio = cur_probs / pre_probs[index]
```

Detailedly, in `reshape` function, the code exclusively using actor network another time is illustrated below:

```
def reshape(self, states):
    pr = self.actor(states).detach()
    print(pr)
```

Here, the usage of actor here is exactly the same as that in iteration steps at all except for states which is a tensor of batchsize of `obs`. However, the output here performs quite strange:

```
tensor([[[1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]],

        [[1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]],

        [[1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]],

        [[1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]],

        [[1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]],

        [[1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]],

        [[1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]],

        [[1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]],

        [[1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]],

        [[1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]],

        [[1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]],
...
```

For each different states, all of the outputs are nothing but only one-vector. This is a phenomenon I never met before, because the same neural network actually showed two completely different, or even error outputs (at least a probability vector should be summed to 1.0), even though I did nothing during this two utilizations. Additionally, it should not be caused by the reasons by such as gradient explosion or vanishment because the network was not learning yet. This is my actor network:

```
class Actor(nn.Module):
  """
  INPUT: 2-dim Tensor, the position as the state of agent
  OUPPUT: 8-dim Teansor, the probability of each actions
  """
  def __init__(self, input, output):
      super(Actor, self).__init__()
      self.dim = 128
      self.fc1 = nn.Linear(input, self.dim)
      self.fc2 = nn.Linear(self.dim, self.dim)

      self.action_head = nn.Linear(self.dim, output)

      # layer normalization
      self.bn1 = nn.LayerNorm(self.dim)
      self.bn2 = nn.LayerNorm(self.dim)

      self.initialization()

  def initialization(self):
    nn.init.xavier_uniform_(self.fc1.weight, gain=nn.init.calculate_gain('relu'))
    nn.init.xavier_uniform_(self.fc2.weight, gain=nn.init.calculate_gain('relu'))


  def forward(self, x):
      x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
      x = self.bn1(x)
      x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
      x = self.bn2(x)
      x = self.action_head(x)
      action_prob = F.softmax(x, dim=1)
      return action_prob
```

I hope anyone can tell me what causes this strange performance of my network. Many thanks!